# CakePHP calling a function from app_controller from child

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Im wondering if someone could help me out a little.

I have a controller called room_controller.php in which i have a function that i want to call a function from the app_controller.php but it doesnt seem to be working, my code is as follows;

```
class RoomController extends AppController {

    function search_people() {
        parent::search_people();
    }

}
```

Above is my child controller, below is the app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller

    function search_people() {
        $this->log('I am running now');
    }

}
```

I'm using a very old version of CakePHP ( 1.3 )

Any help getting this going would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you receive an error? try adding `public` on your function

Comment: Hey @Beginner that seems to have worked ... Thank you

Comment: no problem :)...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this, given to me by @Beginner was to add the `public` keyword to the function in the app_controller

```
class AppController extends Controller

    public function search_people() {
        $this->log('I am running now');
    }

}
```